# MKMapKit module on iOS 8

Tags: ios, module, xcode6, mapkit

With modules and `@import` I assumed you don't need to add the framework manually, it'll atomatically add the framework to the project for you.

Then I was doing a quick test adding to a new project the @import MapKit module and bound a property to a MapView in Interface Builder. 
When I tried this App I get this message 
`'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named MKMapView`'

which means the MapKit framework isn't added to the project, so why is not adding the framework if I'm using modules?

The version I'm running is XCode 6.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Enable the below option can help you to resolve he issue.

Targets -> Capabilities -> Maps -> Enable it (Disable by default)

Refer here
[image]